# How would I expose AWS credentials via Java properties for the AWS Parameter Store Spring Property Source

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, aws-ssm, aws-sdk-java-2.0

From the docs: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.0.0.RC2/single/spring-cloud-aws.html#_parameter_store_configuration_credentials_and_region_configuration

> The Parameter Store Configuration support uses a bootstrap context to configure a default AWSSimpleSystemsManagement client, which uses a com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain and com.amazonaws.regions.DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain

The docs for the provider chain: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html

I'm hoping to avoid using environment variables or command-line properties, as there's a pretty good chance those will leak into logs somewhere in prod. The best option I see is to use a .properties file. According to the first link, since the module is loaded in the bootstrap context, I'd imagine the "Spring" way to do this would be to include these properties in a bootstrap.properties file (per the spring-cloud docs: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_the_bootstrap_application_context)

So my project looks like this:

/src/main/resources/bootstrap.properties

```
aws.accessKeyId = SECRET
aws.secretKey   = ALSOSECRET
```

pom.xml

```
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Finchley.RC2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RC2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
....
```

Note that I'm also exposing the AWS_REGION environment variable, that was the first hurdle to overcome. I'm running Java 8, and can replicate the below behavior running from both Eclipse and command-line Maven.

On startup, I get this stacktrace:

```
2018-06-11 13:20:57.092  INFO 2272 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@359f7cdf: startup date [Mon Jun 11 13:20:57 CDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-11 13:20:57.613  INFO 2272 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$459ef732] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.1.RELEASE)

2018-06-11 13:21:00.301 ERROR 2272 --- [           main] c.a.p.AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator : Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from AWS Parameter Store:
Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
2018-06-11 13:21:00.308 ERROR 2272 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:131) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.251.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1164) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.251.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:762) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.251.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:724) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.251.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.251.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.251.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.251.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.251.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.251.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.doInvoke(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:6573) ~[aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.11.251.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.invoke(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:6549) ~[aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.11.251.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.executeGetParametersByPath(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:4204) ~[aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.11.251.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.getParametersByPath(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClient.java:4180) ~[aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.11.251.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.paramstore.AwsParamStorePropertySource.getParameters(AwsParamStorePropertySource.java:67) ~[spring-cloud-aws-parameter-store-config-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.paramstore.AwsParamStorePropertySource.init(AwsParamStorePropertySource.java:52) ~[spring-cloud-aws-parameter-store-config-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.paramstore.AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator.create(AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator.java:111) ~[spring-cloud-aws-parameter-store-config-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.paramstore.AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator.locate(AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator.java:94) ~[spring-cloud-aws-parameter-store-config-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:94) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RC2.jar:2.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:633) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:373) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.company.app.App.main(App.java:10) [classes/:na]
```

Should I expect this module to have visibility to properties from bootstrap.properties? How else should I provide properties to the bootstrap context?

Comment: The Springiest way for AWS credentials is letting IAM provide credentials as environmental properties, which requires no code whatsoever, it just works in the cloud. On a local test setting you can use your own properties file. The upside to having IAM handle the credentials is that you don't need to build a new deployment package to update your credentials, it's just recreating the instance.

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid relying on the native EC2-ness of the prod environment, I like keeping my apps portable. Which is why I'd rather use the more standard Java properties. I'm also not planning on baking these properties into the JAR, I'm deploying an overrides property alongside the JAR in production. I'm assuming a bootstrap.properties file next to the jar should get picked up as well, but seeing as how the bootstrap.properties file in the project itself isn't working, I'm not sure how this is supposed to work...

Comment: The other option is to provide your own CredentialsProvider where your AWS-using code is. You would, for example, with an Sns client, set the CredentialsProvider, and set your own Credentials inside. This could use Spring @Configuration properties.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm hoping to avoid using environment variables or command-line properties, as there's a pretty good chance those will leak into logs somewhere in prod.

Actually, AWS is nice enough about this to handle most of the dirty work for you. Your concern is that your credentials will be in open plain text in logs, now and forever, and you want to store your credentials in a file that would be managed by some sort of version/repo system instead. AWS acknowledges this a possible option, but really lays it out that it doesn't think that it's the best solution due to the amount of work involved.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html

> You could have your developers store AWS credentials directly within the EC2 instance and allow applications in that instance to use those credentials. But developers would then have to manage the credentials and ensure that they securely pass the credentials to each instance and update each EC2 instance when it's time to rotate the credentials. That's a lot of additional work.

You can configure AWS to use IAM roles to provide temporary credentials for your EC2 instance when you deploy your app. These roles are limited to access you define, and expire after a short period, perhaps a few hours at most.

The error message you have posted would not happen at all in your properly configured EC2 instance. To run in your local test environment, or off the cloud, you can provide credentials in the .aws/credentials store without having to provide any sort of credentials for access to your QA/PROD EC2 boxes, because the .aws/credentials path isn't checked until after the environmental variables.

This results in immediate benefits for your security and sanity: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html

> You do not have to distribute or embed long-term AWS security credentials with an application.
>
> You can provide access to your AWS resources to users without having to define an AWS identity for them. Temporary credentials are the basis for roles and identity federation.
>
> The temporary security credentials have a limited lifetime, so you do not have to rotate them or explicitly revoke them when they're no longer needed. After temporary security credentials expire, they cannot be reused. You can specify how long the credentials are valid, up to a maximum limit.